# Jenkins pipeline sh does not seem to respect pipe in shell command

Tags: jenkins, pipe, jenkins-pipeline, subshell

I am using a Jenkinsfile in a pipeline on version 2.32.2.

For various reasons I want to extract the version string from the pom.  I was hoping I wouldn't have to add the maven help plugin and use evaluate.

I quickly came up with a little sed expression to get it out of the pom which uses pipes and works on the commandline in the jenkins workspace on the executor.

`$ sed -n '/<version>/,/<version/p' pom.xml | head -1 | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*<\/*version>//g'
1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`

It could probably be optimized, but I want to understand why the pipeline seems to be failing on piped sh commands.  I've played with various string formats and am currently using a dollar slashy string.

The pipeline step looks like the following to allow for easy output of the command string:

```
script {
    def ver_script = $/sed -n '/<version>/,/<version/p' pom.xml | head -1 | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*<\/*version>//g'/$
    echo "${ver_script}"
    POM_VERSION = sh(script: "${ver_script}", returnStdout: true)
    echo "${POM_VERSION}"
}
```

When run in the jenkins pipeline I get the following console output where it seems to be separating the piped commands into separate commands:

```
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
sed -n '/<version>/,/<version/p' pom.xml | head -1 | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*<\/*version>//g'
[Pipeline] sh
[FRA-198-versioned-artifacts-44SD6DBQOGOI54UEF7NYE4ECARE7RMF7VQYXDPBVFOHS5CMSTFLA] Running shell script
+ sed -n /<version>/,/<version/p pom.xml
+ head -1
+ sed s/[[:blank:]]*<\/*version>//g
sed: couldn't write 89 items to stdout: Broken pipe
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
```

Any guidance out there on how to properly use piped commands in a jenkinsfile ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know this kind of late answer, but whoever you who needs the solution without eval you can use `/bin/bash -c "script"` to make pipe works

```
script {
    POM_VERSION = sh(script: "/bin/bash -c 'sed -n \'/<version>/,/<version/p\' pom.xml | head -1 | sed \'s/[[:blank:]]*<\/*version>//g\'\''", returnStdout: true)
    echo "${POM_VERSION}"
}
```

The only problem with this method is `hellish escape` yet this way the subshell of pipe will be handled by our boy `/bin/bash -c`

Answer (score 10):

I finally put some thought into it and realized that pipe subshells are probably causing the issue.  I know some of the evils of eval but I ended up wrappping this in an eval:

```
script {
    def ver_script = $/eval "sed -n '/<version>/,/<version/p' pom.xml | head -1 | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*<\/*version>//g'"/$
    echo "${ver_script}"
    POM_VERSION = sh(script: "${ver_script}", returnStdout: true)
    echo "${POM_VERSION}"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If your environment allows it, I've found a simple solution to this problem to be to place your script containing pipes into a file, and then run that with sh, like so:

**script.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh
kubectl exec --container bla -i $(kubectl get pods | awk '/foo-/{ print $1 }') -- php /code/dostuff
```

**Jenkinsfile**:

```
stage('Run script with pipes') {
  steps {
    sh "./script.sh"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [pipeline-utility-steps](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Utility+Steps+Plugin) plugin nowadays includes a [`readMavenPom`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-readmavenpom-code-read-a-maven-project-file) step, which allows to access the version as follows:

```java
version = readMavenPom.getVersion()
```

Comment: Thanks, great pointer to accomplish the end goal, but I was generally curious about the behavior of pipes in sh steps.  Took me a minute to think about the sub-shelling and not a gotcha that I saw mentioned in the docs or occurred to me immediately when trying to do quick and dirty sh steps.

Comment: @sporkthrower did you ever figure out more on the potential sub-shelling or an explanation behind that behavior?

Comment: not really, your example is pretty complex, not sure if it's because of sub-shelling or some syntax weirdness

Answer (score 2):

So nothing detailed above worked for me using the scripted Jenkinsfile syntax with Groovy. I was able to get it working, however. The type of quotations you use are important. In the example below, I am trying to fetch the latest git tag from GitHub.

```
...

stage("Get latest git tag") {
  if (env.CHANGE_BRANCH == 'master') {
    sh 'git fetch --tags'
    TAGGED_COMMIT = sh(script: 'git rev-list --branches=master --tags --max-count=1', returnStdout: true).trim()
    LATEST_TAG = sh(script: 'git describe --abbrev=0 --tags ${TAGGED_COMMIT}', returnStdout: true).trim()
    VERSION_NUMBER = sh(script: "echo ${LATEST_TAG} | cut -d 'v' -f 2", returnStdout: true).trim()
    echo "VERSION_NUMBER: ${VERSION_NUMBER}"
    sh 'echo "VERSION_NUMBER: ${VERSION_NUMBER}"'
  }
}
...
```

Notice how the shell execution to assign `LATEST_TAG` works as expected (assigning the variable to `v2.1.0`). If we were to try the same thing (with single quotes) to assign `VERSION_NUMBER`, it would NOT work - the pipe messes everything up. Instead, we wrap the script in double quotes.

The first echo prints `VERSION_NUMBER: 2.1.0` but the second prints `VERSION_NUMBER:`.  If you want `VERSION_NUMBER` to be available in the shell commands, you have to assign the output of the shell command to `env.VERSION_NUMBER` as shown below:

```
...

stage("Get latest git tag") {
  if (env.CHANGE_BRANCH == 'master') {
    sh 'git fetch --tags'
    TAGGED_COMMIT = sh(script: 'git rev-list --branches=master --tags --max-count=1', returnStdout: true).trim()
    LATEST_TAG = sh(script: 'git describe --abbrev=0 --tags ${TAGGED_COMMIT}', returnStdout: true).trim()
    env.VERSION_NUMBER = sh(script: "echo ${LATEST_TAG} | cut -d 'v' -f 2", returnStdout: true).trim()
    echo "VERSION_NUMBER: ${VERSION_NUMBER}"
    sh 'echo "VERSION_NUMBER: ${VERSION_NUMBER}"'
  }
}
...
```

The first echo prints `VERSION_NUMBER: 2.1.0` and the second prints `VERSION_NUMBER: 2.1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I am also struggling with the usage of pipe inside my jenkins pipeline but as a side note, if you want a simple way to extract the version of a maven pom, here's a very clean one I found in another post and that I'm using :

```
stage('Preparation') {
 version = getVersion()
 print "version : " + version
}
def getVersion() {
  def matcher = readFile('pom.xml') =~ '<version>(.+)</version>'
  matcher ? matcher[0][1] : null
}
```

gives you :

```
[Pipeline] echo
releaseVersion : 0.1.24
[Pipeline] sh
```

Comment: There's no need do such thing anymore. See my answer using the `readMavenPom` step.

Comment: Great ! I will use that immediately. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way I found that works, notice 3 different "types" of quotes:

1. Double quotes.
2. Single quotes.
3. Backticks.

Here is my code:

```
sh " ssh -i "+list[i][4]+" "+backupUser+"@"+list[i][0]+" /bin/bash -c  '`(ps uax |grep \"java -jar couchDbBackup.jar\" | grep -v \"grep\" | awk \"{print \$2}\" | xargs kill -9) ||true`' true"
```

Explanation:

1. `sh "` - start and end with double quotes
2. `ssh -i`  - pass private key to ssh
3. `"+list[i][4]+"` - add a value of the pipeline variable to the string (no magic so far just use double quotes to "exit" string)
4. `"+backupUser+"@"+list[i][0]+"` - user and hostname same like 4
5. `/bin/bash -c`  - calling bash to wrap my command
6. `'` - open a single quote that will span the whole command (else step 7 will not work) this is used to force Jenkins to treat the inside as a string.
7. `` ` `` - opening backticks. Apparently, bash doesn't care and treats them as quotes.
8. `(ps uax |grep \"java -jar couchDbBackup.jar\" | grep -v \"grep\" | awk \"{print \$2}\" | xargs kill -9)` - my set of commands with double quotes escaped with `/` for parameters. Everything is surrounded by round brackets.Brackets are not necessary if you do not need step 9
9. `||true` - since my commands don't always return success I'm adding "OR true" to keep bash and Jenkins from stopping the pipeline.
10. `` `' `` - close backticks and single quotes.
11. `true"` - since Jenkins will consider text inside backticks as empty I add the final "true" (so that Jenkins will see something was passed to `bash -c`) and close the whole string with double quotes.