# Run bash command on jenkins pipeline

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins, groovy

Inside a groovy script (for a jenkins pipeline): How can I run a `bash` command instead of a `sh` command?

**I have tried the following:**

Call "`#!/bin/bash`" inside the `sh` call:

```
stage('Setting the variables values') {
    steps {
         sh '''
            #!/bin/bash
            echo "hello world"
         '''
    }
}
```

Replace the `sh` call with a `bash` call:

```
stage('Setting the variables values') {
    steps {
         bash '''
            #!/bin/bash
            echo "hello world"
         '''
    }
}
```

**Additional Info:**

My command is more complex than a `echo hello world`.

Comment: What is your question ? Please formulate your question clearly and provide the problems details you are facing.

Comment: I think we have the same problem. Even with the second example, it still executes with sh instead of bash. Is that what you are seeing?

Comment: Yes, it is! A create a solution adding a .bash file on my git repository, so i speak to Jenkins run it on a specific path inside of my  project.

Comment: Please see my answer on this StackOverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57381691/10398126

Comment: Take a look at my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57381691/10398126

Comment: Please see my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57381691/10398126

Answer (score 167, accepted):

The Groovy script you provided is formatting the first line as a blank line in the resultant script. The shebang, telling the script to run with /bin/bash instead of /bin/sh, needs to be on the first line of the file or it will be ignored.

So instead, you should format your Groovy like this:

```
stage('Setting the variables values') {
    steps {
         sh '''#!/bin/bash
                 echo "hello world" 
         '''
    }
}
```

And it will execute with /bin/bash.

Comment: @Jake Any idea how you gen use a bash-specific script in a stage? This part works for me too, but when I try to trigger a bash script it does not work for me.

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'bash' found among steps`

Comment: For multi-line scripts or those run multiple times, I would create a new bash script file (starting from #!/bin/bash), and simply run it with: chmod +x './script.sh' && sh './script.sh'

Comment: You can also just use newline in the same string: `sh '#!/bin/bash\n echo "$SHELL"'`

Comment: Alternatively, one can also get rid of the first blank line like so: `'''\ `

Answer (score 19):

According to [this document](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/215171038-How-do-I-run-a-different-Shell-interpreter-in-a-Pipeline-Script), you should be able to do it like so:

```
node {
    sh "#!/bin/bash \n" + 
       "echo \"Hello from \$SHELL\""
}
```

Comment: The logo returns a error for the "+"

WorkflowScript: 9: illegal string body character after dollar sign;
   solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 9, column 68.
   2c-437a-b8a2-db013fe42f62\"" +

Comment: Can you please post the script? From what you've pasted, it looks like there are two quotes before the `+`, which is wrong.

Comment: Thank you @Jacob I was having the same problem and your comment helped me to solve those!

Comment: Don't use "\n" and "+", just use tripple quotes to do a multi-line string.

Answer (score 13):

For multi-line shell scripts or those run multiple times, I would create a new bash script file (starting from `#!/bin/bash`), and simply run it with `sh` from Jenkinsfile:

```
sh 'chmod +x ./script.sh'
sh './script.sh'
```

Answer (score 12):

I'm sure that the above answers work perfectly. However, I had the difficulty of adding the double quotes as my bash lines where closer to 100. So, the following way helped me. (In a nutshell, no double quotes around each line of the shell)

Also, when I had "bash '''#!/bin/bash" within steps, I got the following error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '**bash**' found among steps`

```
pipeline {
    agent none

    stages {

        stage ('Hello') {
            agent any

            steps {
                echo 'Hello, '

                sh '''#!/bin/bash

                    echo "Hello from bash"
                    echo "Who I'm $SHELL"
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result of the above execution is

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you want to change your default shell to `bash` for *all* projects on Jenkins, you can do so in the Jenkins config through the web portal:

Manage Jenkins > Configure System (Skip this clicking if you want by just going to `https://{YOUR_JENKINS_URL}/configure`.)

Fill in the field marked 'Shell executable' with the value `/bin/bash` and click 'Save'.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to execute a Shell script in bash via `jenkinsfile`. Here's what worked for me :

`sh 'core_devops/automation/scripts/ecs_initialize.sh'`

And the first line in the script had

`#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is indeed that the shebang is ignored if it doesn't start at the very beginning of the file.

As an alternative to mangling the formatting for `Jenkinsfile` readers, I've taken to using this:

```
sh label: 'Run fancy bash script',
   script: '''
       #!/usr/bin/env  bash

       echo "Hello ${SHELL}!"
   '''.stripIndent().stripLeading()
```

Note that `stripIndent()` is not strictly necessary for it to *work*, but Jenkins logs are a lot nicer with it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case event

```
sh '''#!/bin/bash
      echo "Hello ${SHELL}!"
'''
```

return "Hello /bin/sh"...

after some search I found "sh" was "dash" instead of bash on another terminal

Ubuntu22 :

```
jenkins@ubuntu22:~$ command -v sh
/usr/bin/sh
jenkins@ubuntu22:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Mar 23  2022 /usr/bin/sh -> dash
jenkins@ubuntu22:~$ command -v dash
/usr/bin/dash
```

on my old Red Hat 7.4 :

```
[jenkins@RH7.4 ~]$ command -v sh
/usr/bin/sh
[jenkins@RH7.4 ~]$ ls -l /usr/bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Sep  6  2018 /usr/bin/sh -> bash
[jenkins@RH7.4 ~]$ command -v bash
/usr/bin/bash
[jenkins@RH7.4 ~]$ ls -l /usr/bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 960632 Aug  3  2017 /usr/bin/bash
```