# Jenkinsfile not using full docker-compose command, losing build-arg

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

We have a Jenkinsfile that kicks off a docker-compose command. Jenkinsfile bit looks like this

```
  sh("""docker-compose build \
    --no-cache \
    --build-arg DATE=${sh([returnStdout: true, script: "date -u +%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ  | tr -d '\n'"])} \
    --build-arg VERSION=${sh([returnStdout: true, script: "git describe --tags --always"])} \
    --build-arg SHA=${sh([returnStdout: true, script: "git rev-parse HEAD"])}""")
```

But when I run the build in Jenkins I see it logging out the command as

```
docker-compose build --no-cache --build-arg DATE=20190411T142851Z --build-arg VERSION=470a670
```

These are being passed in to set LABEL items in a Dockerfile. I've tried using Docker and setting the labels manually, but it also truncates afte rthe second label.

It will use the first two or three, regardless of what they are. Anything after those labels (or build-args for docker-compose) is chopped off and not used.

For example, the docker command used was this

```
  sh("""docker build \
    --no-cache \
    --label com.<company>.name="Some stuff" \
    --label com.<company>.build-date=${sh([returnStdout: true, script: "date -u +%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ  | tr -d '\n'"])} \
    --label com.<company>.version=${sh([returnStdout: true, script: "git describe --tags --always"])} \
    --label com.<company>.repo-sha=${sh([returnStdout: true, script: "git rev-parse HEAD"])} \
    --tag ${folderName} \
    .""")
```

and that led to this error

```
docker build --no-cache --label com.<company>.name='Some stuff' --label com.<company>.build-date=20190410T192516Z --label com.<company>.version=9bfbd1b
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
```

It cut off the tag and the period for the directory.

Comment: Update: Looks like it's an issue with the sh() command. Digging in to where we get that from. I did a println of the full command and it showed up.

Comment: Sadly it's even dumber than that. Posting an answer.

Comment: Yeah never mind: you are right. I read through the question too quickly. This could be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392267/running-nested-commands-in-jenkins-pipeline-shell/47394132#47394132

Comment: Oh well, I'll take this as a learning experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'm a moron.

`git describe --tags --always` returns a new line, so I needed `| tr -d '\n'` in that as well. I didn't write the original date command and should have looked at that earlier.