# Pipeline by using Jenkins with private SVN repository

Tags: jenkins, svn

I am trying to implement CI/CD pipeline for my microservice oriented project by using Kubernetes and Jenkins. I am using my code repository on my on-premise server. I created one SVN repository on my server.

I am interested to know, can I use my private SVN code repository with Jenkins?

The reason for my doubt is because every example is showing the creation of pipeline with Jenkins and GitHub project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the shell command in your pipeline. So you are free to use SVN with Jenkins:
https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-cli-main.html

Some info there:
[Run bash command on jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330148/run-bash-command-on-jenkins-pipeline)