# Grep all number from end of string upto any other char?, and save both parts to variables?

Tags: bash, variables, grep

I am trying grep only the numbers from the end of the string until any other char, so from example:
`"Version 1.2.34"` Will give me `'34'` to variable `$minor` and `'Version 1.2.'` to variable `$type`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
minor=$(grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,24}')
```

but this gives me ALL numbers.

Comment: Add `$` at the end of the regexp so it only matches at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pure `bash`:

```sh
s="Version 1.2.34"

minor="${s##*[!0-9]}"
type="${s%$minor}"

declare -p type minor
declare -- type="Version 1.2."
declare -- minor="34"
```

Comment: Hey, it works in Bash but not in Jenkinsfile: ```WorkflowScript: 62: unexpected char: '#' @ line 62, column 29.
                   minor=sh"${s##*[!0-9]}"```. any idea why?

Comment: Sorry there was no mention of Jenkinsfile. May be you are not using `bash` in your Jenkinsfile. [Check this answer for using bash interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45179743/548225)

Comment: thx, I will check it :)