# "@git: not found" in Linux stage of Jenkins file

Tags: linux, git, shell, jenkins

I am trying to add stage in Linux Jenkins file. And trying to run `git` command from it but getting error in command:

```
def tag_description = sh(script: '@git describe --tags --exact-match HEAD', returnStdout: true).trim()
```

Error:

```
@git: not found
```

Appreciate your help

Thanks

Comment: What is `@git`? Looks like a typo for me.

Comment: Hi @UlrichEckhardt, I am running it for Linux. So is that command correct ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Where did you get that from? Perhaps that was Windows cmd.exe code, where the `@` is used to silence the output (IIRC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am running it for Linux. So is that command correct ?

No, the command should be `git ...`, not `@git`.

You have more advanced `sh(script:(...)` examples in "[Run bash command on jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44330148/6309)", and none of them have a `@` in them.

```
sh label: 'Run fancy bash script',
   script: '''
       #!/usr/bin/env  bash

       echo "Hello ${SHELL}!"
   '''.stripIndent().stripLeading()
```

Or, as in "[How do I get the output of a shell command executed using into a variable from Jenkinsfile (groovy)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53254497/6309)":

```
try {
    // Fails with non-zero exit if dir1 does not exist
    def dir1 = sh(script:'ls -la dir1', returnStdout:true).trim()
} catch (Exception ex) {
    println("Unable to read dir1: ${ex}")
}
```

Comment: Hi @VonC, Ohk then I just need to remove "@" from it,  then its correct right?

Comment: @Digital_AI That is the idea, yes.

Comment: And how can I add condition before that, what is the syntax for that for ex: `iscommnet = True`

Comment: @Digital_AI you can use the [shell syntax for if clauses](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/if-else-in-shell-scripts): `def tag_description = sh(script: 'if [[ "${iscomment}" == "True" ]]; then echo "comment"; else git describe --tags --exact-match HEAD; fi', returnStdout: true).trim()`