# Give Jenkins a parameter string/array and then iterate over it

Tags: bash, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job where I define three string parameters to be entered by the user:

```
IMAGE="hello-world goodbye-world"
REPO="not.a.real.repo.net/fake"
TAG="latest"
```

```
list=( $IMAGE )
for n in ${list[@]}
do
docker tag $n:$tag $repo/$n:$tag
docker push $repo/$n:$tag
done
```

I want to allow the user to input multiple images into the `IMAGE` string and then iterate over that to automate pushing our docker containers to a remote repo.

This works when I run it locally but I can't get it to fire from within the job.  The error is :

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

So it feels like it doesn't like to convert the `$IMAGE` to a list or array, perhaps there is another way to do it?

Comment: Oh, I see. This is a bash script. Jenkins is incidental.

Comment: Google [says](https://ioflood.com/blog/bash-split-string-into-array/) you'd replace `list=( $IMAGE )` with `read -a list <<< "$IMAGE"`. I think a reason that you get different results depending on how you run it may be because your Jenkins [is using `sh`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330148/run-bash-command-on-jenkins-pipeline) (or some other shell) rather than `bash`.

Comment: I bet your script is not run by bash. Put it into a script file and execute it explicitly by bash.

Comment: @user1934428 You were right it was executing as a sh script and not using bash which didn't have the ability to expand the string param to an array.

Thanks for the sanity check!