Jenkinsfile Groovy -> sh in the pipeline - still calls csh - how to run sh stanza as BASH
Jenkins 2.334.x
Build node: RHEL 8.6
Jenkins job's user (service account is: svc_user.
The default shell assigned to this user is csh
In my Jenkinsfile code, I have the following code in one of the stages.
      // Tried both ways
      //sh label: 'some_stage', script: '''#!/bin/bash
        sh '''#!/bin/bash 
          echo "SHELL = $SHELL"
          which git
          # some more commands here
      '''

I'm getting SHELL = /bin/csh even though I tried to tell Jenkins to use shebang #!/bin/bash in the first line.
What am I missing in the syntax. How can I tell Jenkins to execute the above stanza in BASH?
What's the issue in the above syntax?
Creation of a small wrapper shell script with #!/bin/bash shebang is an alternative which I can't do for now.

lol. who is busy closing this post? This is a valid question and similar question on SO have high votes. Also, if you don't know the solution, why voting to close?
Close this one too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330148/run-bash-command-on-jenkins-pipeline My post is not a duplicate of this post but related as the solution here, didn't work for me.

You are executing it in bash. $SHELL variable is set to a user default shell, not to the current interpreter - change the shebang from bash to dash or ksh and see for yourself.
